# What's the translation of "rubberneck" in French?

Tags: traduction

To rubberneck [means](https://www.google.com/search?q=rubberneck):

> To turn one's head to stare at something in a foolish manner.
>
> Example: "a passerby rubbernecking at the accident scene"

What's the translation of "rubberneck" in French?

Google translate and DeepL didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a translation in a Robert-Collins dictionary; however, I don't like it very much; for one thing, there is no twisting of the neck implied.

> **rubberneck** faire le badaud

- a passerby rubbernecking at the accident scene: *un passant qui faisait le badaud sur la scène d'un accident*

A precise translation requires quite some phrasing. The following is an option of multi word translation.

- un passant *qui se tordait le cou dans un regard bête* sur  une scène d'accident

Comment: @viande-à-chien Je ne pense pas que l'on doive extrapoler et parler de gymnastique (turn, se tordre); il s'agit d'un déplacement de la tête inconfortable parce que poussé à l'extrême, mais c'est tout. On trouve de nombreux exemples (Unexpected love: Shadows of the past, books.google.fr › books 2020
Nous ? réagit Mackensie avec une seconde de retard. — Wade, Blake et Brody sont avec moi, avoua Samantha. Mackensie se tordit le cou pour regarder à l'extérieur,)

Comment: @viande-à-chien Non, l'extrapolation c'est vous qui,la faite en parlant de gymnastique alors qu'il ne s'agit que  d'un mouvement, et puis le texte du PO et les dictionnaires sont clairs,  il y a un mouvement du corps (OALD : to turn to look at something …). Mon propos n'évoque pas le torticolis, lisez les exemples qui vous ont été fournis (encore une fois : https://www.google.com/search?q=%22se%20tordit%20le%20cou%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr), et ne niez pas l'évidence, et enfin, ne supprimer pas vos commentaires quand vous les jugez compromettants, plus personne ne comprend  la discusssion.

Answer (score 1):

*A passerby [rubbernecking](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rubbernecking) at the accident scene.*

> Un passant qui s'arrête pour voir un accident.
>  Un passant qui [fait](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/rubberneck/608618)
> le [badaud](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/badaud)/[badaude](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/badauder) lors d'un accident.
> Un passant qui flâne sur les lieux d'un accident.
> Un passant [à l'affût de](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_l%E2%80%99aff%C3%BBt) tout ce qui se passe sur les lieux d'un
> accident.
> Un [curieux](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/badaud) qui s'[attarde](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/attarder) sur les lieux d'un accident.